# How to define generic methods in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

In node.js I struggle with classes/objects and the 'this' keyword.  E.g:

```
function Set(arr,leq) {
  this.leq = leq ? leq : function(x,y) {return x<=y;};
  this.arr=arr.slice().sort(this.geq);
}
Set.prototype.geq=function(x,y) { return this.leq(y,x);}

var myset = new Set([1,5,3,2,7,9]);


TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'leq'
at [object Context]:1:47
at Array.sort (native)
at new Set ([object Context]:3:22)
at [object Context]:1:13
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
```

However, if I remove the `.sort` fragment like this:

```
function Set(arr,leq) {
  this.leq = leq ? leq : function(x,y) {return x<=y;};
  this.arr=arr.slice();
}
```

I have no problems with:

```
 var myset = new Set([1,5,3,2,7,9]);
 myset.geq(3,4)
 false
```

but still:

```
 myset.arr.sort(myset.geq)

 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'leq'
 at ...
```

So: How do I create a method (like `geq`) in my object that has access to another method (like `leq`) in the same object when I need to access the first method to e.g. the `sort` function?

Comment: Isn't this a pure JavaScript question? Suggest retag --node.js

Answer (score 2):

```
this.leq = leq ? leq : function(x,y) {return x<=y;};
```

Will only assign the `leq` function to the current *instance* of `Set`

```
this.arr=arr.slice().sort(this.geq);
```

Won't work because passing a function reference as `instance.methodName` does not bind that method to the specified instance

This may be solved using [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: +1 for point 2, but I'm confused by your point 1.  Methods on the prototype can be called against the instance as though they were on the instance itself. OP would have the same issue if the method was on the instance. Or have I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: Thanks, @Alnitak.  I wasn't aware of the `bind` method. Here is a working solution for those who might be interested, i.e. replace the third line in the first code fragment with `this.arr=arr.slice().sort(this.geq.bind(this));`